# Access NSMutableArray from a different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a class where a NSMutableArray object is formed, as so:

```
navBarColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:colourOfNavBar, nil];
```

I then have another class, which has the first class added to it properly, but it won't let me access the NSMutableArray from the first class. This line of code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [HandlingPalettes.navBarColour objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Returns:

expected ':' before '.' token

But:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [navBarColour objectAtIndex:0]);
```

would work in the original class.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider naming arrays in plural form: navBarColours. Then it is immidiately clear it's either an array or a set. Otherwise people will think it's a UIColor and the final app will crash and suck.

Answer (score 3):

The dot notation is used differently in objective c that from c++ or java. In objective-c it is shorthand for accessing a property. You need to have defined a objective-c property first, like this:

in the .h file (INSIDE the interface tag)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *navBarColor;
```

in the .m file (INSIDE the implementation tag)

```
@synthesize navBarColor;
```

Only then can you access the array with the dot notation.

Comment: please post what you've written (h and m file). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Actually, futureelite7 & Radek S aren't strictly correct, in that you don't need `@property` declaration to use dot notation. If there's a getter method called `navBarColour` then the dot notation works fine for that too. But that's another issue.)

The declaration for the property `navBarColour` must visible to your code containing the `NSLog`. Yes, do post your header file, if you say the added `@property` declaration is also failing to compile then you have something weird going on. Make sure your other class' .m is including that header, and that `HandlingPalettes`'s class isn't merely declared with a forward declaration say (`@class Blah;`).

But also, is `HandlingPalettes` a class or an instance?!? Identifiers starting with capitol letters by convention imply its a class name, so that's suspicious. If it's a class name, then that's surely not what you want.

(Regarding using dot notation without `@property`, if `HandlingPalettes` is indeed a class, then if you had the class method `+(NSMutableArray*)navBarColour` then when it *would* compile.)

Answer (score 0):

You must add a [property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) to the object containing the array and synthesize it:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *navBarColour;
```

---

Also, change the compiler to Clang and the error messages will be more clear, if you like.