# Use NSMutableArray in app delegate in another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an `NSMutableArray` in my app delegate. I wish to use that mutable array in a different class in my program, as if it were a global variable. How would I do this?

Is it as simple as importing the header and referencing the object?

Comment: Does it not make sense to use this as an ivar for your delegate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective C: use NSMutableArray in different classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647154/objective-c-use-nsmutablearray-in-different-classes)

Comment: Not to mention [NSMutableArray in other Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516266/) and [Access NSMutableArray from a different Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240240/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of the UIApplication singleton:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then, access your array [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) like this: `appDelegate.yourArrayProperty`

Comment: Will that be entered in the header file? and will I need to import the appDelegate class?

Comment: Yes, you need to import the appDelegate class.

Answer (score 2):

Make you array a property of your delegate as Sean said

```
@property(readonly) NSMutableArray *theArray;
```

Then access the array like this :

```
((YourAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).theArray
```

Comment: I know this is forever old. However, I had a question. If you set your  array to read only wouldnt that defeat the purpose of an NSMutableArray as no view could add to it....making it an NSArray?

Comment: Short answer : No. Long answer : the pointer to the NSMutableArray is read only (ie you can't change the instance of the NSMutableArray) but the array is mutable (and the readonly property can't change that) so you can add/delete items.