# Adding NSString Objects to another ViewController

Tags: nsmutablearray, uitableview, parameter-passing

first of all I've checked a lot of posts in here, but i couldn't find a proper solution. I'm new to ObjC so i'm not able to find a solution by myself!
Problem:
I have a TabBArController with 2 Tabs each of them holds a TableviewController. From my first ViewController i'm tryin to add different Url strings to an Array of my SecondTableViewController.

#### Method from FirstviewController which should add the url to the Array of the SecondViewController:

```
- (IBAction)setJobs:(id)setJobs
{
    NSString *parameterString = [[NSString alloc]init];
    for (UITextField*textField in textFields)
    {
        parameterString = [parameterString stringByAppendingString:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%@,",textField.text]];
    }

    NSString*user = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString*password = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString*firmenId = [[NSString alloc]init];

    user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Username"];
    password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Password"];
    firmenId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirmenId"];

    NSString*urlString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://www.someurl.com/firmenid=%@;projectid=%@;user=%@;kennwort=%@;appparminfo=%@",firmenId,[self.detailRowArray objectAtIndex:1],user,password,parameterString];

    [projektsInUse addObject:urlString];


    // Here the url should be passed to the other Viewcontroller
    TableAnswerController *tAVC=[[TableAnswerController alloc]init];
    [tAVC.tabbleArray addObject:urlString];



    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        //connection didReceiveData
    }
    else
    {
        // Error Handling
    }

}
```

#### here is my SecondTableViewController:

```
#import "TableAnswerController.h"

@interface TableAnswerController ()

@end

@implementation TableAnswerController

@synthesize timer,tabbleArray;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) 
    {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(!self.tabbleArray)
    {
        self.tabbleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
}
- (IBAction)refreshAnswers:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"TableArray: %@",tabbleArray);

}
```

## Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array first

```
TableAnswerController *tAVC=[[TableAnswerController alloc]init];
 tAVC = [NSMutableArray new];
[tAVC.tabbleArray addObject:urlString];
```

OR

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:urlString, nil];
[tAVC setTabbleArr:arr];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both solutions, but they did not work out. The array is still empty.

Comment: remove this line     if(!self.tabbleArray)
    {
        self.tabbleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

Comment: and check the following things, if ur urlString is correct and if u push/use the right controller.

Comment: Sry for asking like a dummy, but what do you mean with push/use the right controller? I removed the if line, but nothing happened.

Comment: If I add this line:
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tAVC animated:YES];
My app crashes with this error: 


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/AUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/EBB31E95-D653-43EE-BFB7-0A72B3ADF966/Infopainter v1.0.app> (loaded)' with name 'TableAnswerController''
*** First throw call stack:....

Comment: Thanks For your Help!
I figured it out by myself. I used the AppDelegate to create an NSMutableArray which is used somehow like a global variable. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061659/use-nsmutablearray-in-app-delegate-in-another-class